# How to enable arithmetic between Lua basic types?

Tags: lua

Popular scripting languages allow for expressions like this

```
true*5>10.3*false
```

where true is 1 and false is 0, any number besides 0 is also true

Can you do the same in lua ?

Currently im wrapping all operands into a table and use the metamethods like __sub to enable said functionality but it generates verbose code and overhead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See the code below. You can add similar metamethods for the other arithmetic operations.

```
local function b2n(x)
    if x==false then return 0 end
    if x==true  then return 1 end
    return x
end

debug.setmetatable(false,{
    __mul=function(x,y) return b2n(x)*b2n(y) end
})

print(true*5 > 10.3*false)
```

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have access to the debug  table in my environment. I however still marked your answer as correct as it perfectly answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

An approach that – while inferior to "the proper way" as described by lhf – might help you, given that

> Currently im wrapping all operands into a table and use the metamethods like `__sub` to enable said functionality but it generates verbose code and overhead

and

> I do not have access to the debug table in my environment.

is to have functions for coercing values like `N`, `B`, ...

```
function N( x )
   local ty = type( x )
   if ty == "number" then  return x  end
   if ty == "boolean" then  return x and 1 or 0  end
   -- and so on for other types you need to handle
end
```

and then you'd say `B(v) and (N(x)*N(y) > N(z)+N(w))` or something like that.  While there's still lots of function calls, it's probably faster than wrapping everything in tables and (depending on how/where you do the wrapping) this may also be more readable.

If you're writing library-like code, doing the coercion on the top level (in the exposed library functions, right after receiving values / where you'd normally do type checks) means you'll always have values of the right type inside your library and don't need these coercion functions in there.  So it'll essentially just be type checking / automatic coercion at the entry points and normal code after.

If you're using this for convenience inside your code (say, interpreting the result of a comparison as 0 or 1 for arithmetic), you'll know exactly what needs wrapping and the rest can stay unwrapped.

In either case, this is probably faster / more readable than wrapping things in tables.